# How Can I call HTTPS function with 'firebase functions:shell'?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I don't understand how to call HTTPS functions in local.

I made index.js file and exported `hello` functions and run `firebase functions:shell`.

I read this document, and I followed this way:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-shell#invoke_https_functions

```
# invoke
myHttpsFunction()
myHttpsFunction.get()
myHttpsFunction.post()
```

but I got this message `hello is not defined`

This is index.js I wrote.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const {https} = require('firebase-functions')

admin.initializeApp()

exports.hello = https.onRequest((_, response) => {
  response.end('hello')
})
```

This is terminal.

```sh
$ firebase functions:shell
✔  functions: Using node@8 from host.
✔  functions: Emulator started at http://localhost:5001
i  functions: Watching "/Users/xxx/xxx" for Cloud Functions...
⚠  Default "firebase-admin" instance created!
i  functions: HTTP trigger initialized at http://localhost:5001/xxx/us-central1/hello
i  functions: HTTP trigger initialized at http://localhost:5001/xxx/us-central1/callable
firebase > ⚠  Default "firebase-admin" instance created!
firebase > hello()
ReferenceError: hello is not defined
```

`> firebase > hello()` should be return `hello`, but `hello is not defined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the Firebase CLI emulator.  Please [follow the issue on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1243).  For now, [follow this advice in that issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1243#issuecomment-490153926).

In the future, post bug reports there as well.  There is not much Stack Overflow can help you with in regards to bug reports.